# Как ввести строку

Tags: c++

Нужно ввести строку в с++, неизвестного размера, максимума нет(хоть войну и мир вставляй), желательно с помощью указателя

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: текст романа «война и мир» вам операционная система не даст «ввести». // это намёк на то, что вам надо изучить этот вопрос — какого размера строку можно передать программе на stdin **интерактивно**.

Comment: И в чем проблема собственно заключается?

Comment: Вывести куда? С каким форматированием?

Answer (score 1):

Примера я думаю, вам хватит

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Введите ваше имя: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Привет, " << name << "!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, уже изучил. Вы забыли #include <string>, знаю что это не обязательно в vs, но все же рекомендую не забывать